# How to get Cook's distance and carry out residual analysis for non-lm() and non-glm() models in R?

Tags: r, outliers, residuals, cooks-distance

I usually use the `plot(lm())` or `plot(glm())` (combined with `par(mfrow=c(2,2)`) to analyze residuals. Unfortunately this is not possible whenn estimating a `tobit()` (package [AER](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AER/index.html)) or `zeroinfl()` (package [pscl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/index.html)) model. Furthermore any Cooks distance command does not work. It's either not possible to make the residual analysis in a convienent way, or I just don't understand it. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a short example of what I am talking about:

```
require(AER)
require(stats)
attach(cars)
tob<-tobit(dist~speed)
summary(tob)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(tob)           #doesn't work
cooks.distance(tob) #doesn't work
detach(cars)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the on-line help, the `cooks.distance()` function expects an object of class `lm` or `glm` so it is not possible to get it work with other type of models. It is defined in `src/library/stats/R/lm.influence.R`, from R source, so you can browse the code directly and build your own function if nothing exits in other places. A quick way of seeing what it does is to type `stats:::cooks.distance.lm` at the R prompt, though.

Also, as `tobit` is nothing more than a wrapper for `survreg`, all attached methods to the latter kind of R object might be used. For example, there's a `residuals.survreg` (in the [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) package) S3 method for extracting residuals from objects inheriting from class `survreg`.

Comment: hmm ok so there is any convenient way, no?

Comment: @MarkDollar No one that I can think of. And in fact, I don't know if there exists a dedicated function for Cook distance in Tobit or censored regression. A first start would be to plot the outcome variable against each explanatory variable, to check whether there's any evidence that the errors are not identically and normally distributed. I also found this paper, [Influence diagnostics in the tobit censored response model](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r88515367r5078k4/) which detailed influence measures for Tobit models. (...)

Comment: @MarkDollar (...) You might also take a look at UCLA resources on [Tobit regression with R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/dae/tobit.htm) and check whether the [VGAM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) package they used contains additional diagnostic tools.